# Margin the top menu shifts content

Tags: html, css

There was a problem with the scroll bar on the '.fullpage' block and the content. Due to the indent of the top menu at 30px, the bottom content also leaves the view on those same 30 pixels. How to be?

P.S. Externally, the page should look exactly as done. Top menus should be separate from general content.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
    html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 6px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
}

body {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #141320;
    color: white;
}

.draggable {
    -webkit-app-region: drag;
}

.center {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
}

.center .btn {
    border-radius: 4px; 
    margin: 7px;
}

button {
    -webkit-app-region: no-drag;
}

.fullpage {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.topmenu {
    top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
    z-index: 99999;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="topmenu draggable"></div>
    <div class="fullpage">
        123123123
        <div class="center">
            <button class="btn btn-info">Test</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Test 2</button>
            <button class="btn btn-success test">Test 3</button>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-top: 1400px; width: 30px; height: 31px; background-color: aqua;"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Added: And for some reason, the top menu has ceased to be transparent. Content completely disappears beneath it, as if rgba does not work with transparency (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is settled!

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 6px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #141320;
    color: white;
    z-index: 99998;
}

.draggable {
    -webkit-app-region: drag;
}

button {
    -webkit-app-region: no-drag;
}

.fullpage {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.topmenu {
    top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
    z-index: 99999;
}

.content {
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.center {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
}

    .center .btn {
        border-radius: 4px;
        margin: 7px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="fullpage">
        <div class="topmenu draggable"></div>
        <div class="content">
            123123123
            <div class="center">
                <button class="btn btn-info">Test</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary">Test 2</button>
                <button class="btn btn-success test">Test 3</button>
            </div>
            <div style="margin-top: 1400px; width: 50px; height: 60px; background-color: aqua;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```